# format number in specific currency based on another column data

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS
I have a table with column person, column country, and column salary. I want the column salary in a specific currency format based on column country. For example, if column country is United States, corresponding salary should be displayed in $.
Similarly, if the country column shows India, then the salary column should show a rupee, etc.
I am a starter and unable to do this. Please tell me a simple way of doing this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could return a second dataset with a list of Countries and their Currency symbols such as

```
Country    Currency
USA        USD
India      RUP
UK         GBP
```

Then you can use [LOOKUP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ee210531.aspx) to 'look up' the value in the second datasset from the first, so a dataset of

```
Country    Sales
India      404
UK         44
USA        1255
```

You can then used the lookup as follows

```
=Lookup(Fields!Country.Value, 
        Fields!Country.Value, 
        Fields!Currency.Value, 
        "DataSetCurrency") <--- Blue <Expr> in the example below
```

Remember, you can include more than one Placeholder (expression) in a cell, so a design like this

[image]

Would render as this (DataSetCurrency included for information only)

[image]

Hopefully this will answer your question, though please ask for clarification if required.